# How java recognizes that both objects are of same type

Tags: java, android, oop, polymorphism, type-safety

for example for data safety I create a class e.g ModelClass and defined some properties and methods and define some list like that 
`private List<ModelClass> results;` then how java will know that what I'm passing is really ModelClass, does it compare all the methods and properties of ModelClass and what object I'm passing in results, I'm how java determine that 2 objects are of same type does it compare all fields and methods to know that yes they are of same type,

Yes I know that when I define type they are of same type would have same objects are method but what happens when we pass object as polymorphic objects

I got this feeling from here when I was learning retrofit, in retrofit when we get response its like:

```
public void onResponse(Call<MoviesResponse>call, Response<MoviesResponse> response) {
            List<Movie> movies = response.body().getResults();
            Log.d(TAG, "Number of movies received: " + movies.size());
        }
```

the MovieResponse has same field name which response object return [here](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-retrofit-http-library/)

Comment: You describe "duck typing".  Java uses static typing.  The object knows what class it is, and the supertypes of the class all the way up to Object, and the needed type must be one of those or an implemented interface.

Answer (score 0):

Every object has a record of exactly what class it is, which you can see by calling the `getClass()` method on the said object.  This includes the full name of the class (including the package), as well as information about the fields, methods, superclasses, interfaces, etc.

In your case, all it really does is compare these `Class` objects to make sure they are compatible.

Comment: what about if I define class A and in that I have defined some fields in it like name, age, nationality and created its object and then assign it some object other that has same fields, will name, age, nationality copy to class A object?

Comment: What you just described will not compile.  Just because it has the same fields as an `A`, the same methods as an `A`, does not necessarily make it an `A`. And Java will reject such an attempt at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

The component which does the most type checking is the Java compiler, and it has the complete source code at its disposal, so it can simply check what type variables were declared to have. (For some libraries you may not have the source code, but also the class files contain this type information.)

For example, in the code snippet

```
public void add(ModelClass a) {
    results.add(a);
}
```

the compiler knows that `results` is a reference to `List<ModelClass>` and that `a` is a reference to a `ModelClass`, because that is how they are defined in the source code. So it accepts this code as valid. At runtime, no type checking needs to be performed in this case.

In some cases, in particular when you use the `instanceof` operator or an explicit cast, the JVM must perform type checking at runtime. For this, every Java object knows its own class. You can obtain the class of an object by calling its `getClass()` method.

Note that the compiler checks the defined type of the variables, whereas at runtime the type of the object is checked (which the compiler cannot know). The latter is always a subtype of the former. Additionally, for historical reasons, at runtime generic type information is lost. So `results.getClass()` will return `ArrayList.class` (or another `List` implementation), not `List<ModelClass>.class` (or something like that).

Answer (score 0):

To understand that process you need to know two things:
how to obtain a class information of given object and how to compare two pieces of these.

**So how java actually knows the object class?**

At runtime classes are same objects as everything else. Every common object stores a reference to the class object. And every class stores a reference to it's superclass.

**To store an object in** `List<Movie>` **the object type should be directly `Movie` or it may be it's successor.
Having two classes how do you say if one is the same or at least a successor of another?**

Operator `instanceof`, that's how!

```
final Movie a = new Movie(...);
final String b = "Not a Movie";

a instanceof Movie; // expression is true
b instanceof Movie; // false
```

Let's say you have classes hierarchy

`Object`(0) -> `Video`(1) -> `Movie` (2) -> `HollywoodMovie` (3)

And code

```
final HollywoodMovie a = new HollywoodMovie(...);
a instanceof Video; // true, how it works?
```

Second line's `instanceof` will do these steps:

1. Checks if type of `a` has at least two nodes at class hierarchy (because `Video` is second in it's own hierarchy)
2. If previous is true checks if the second node is `Video`

This is an approximation of `instanceof` work

Answer (score -1):

I think,when you add one object into List<**ModelClass**> *results*, the first action is type checking like `if(object instanceof ModelClass){...}`

Comment: No it isn't. There is a compile-time check.